# Laravel database connection: Selecting from database name in snake case

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm starting to learn Laravel. I've run through the example instructions from the site successfully and now I'm trying a second run through and I'm running into an issue.

I'm trying to connect to a database called `zipCodes` and has one table called `zipCodeDetails`.

In my Laravel project I have a model containing the following code:

```
<?php
class ZipCodeDetails extends Eloquent {}
```

And in my `routes.php` file I have the following code:

```
Route::get('zipCodes', function (){

    $zipCodes = ZipCodeDetails::all();
    return View::make('zipCodes')->with('zipCodes', $zipCodes);
});
```

The error I'm running into is when I try to load the URL:

```
http://localhost:8888/zipCodes
```

In my browser I'm getting the error code:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'zipcodes.zip_code_details' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `zip_code_details`)
```

There's nothing written in my code where I define the database `zipCodes` as `zipcodes` or the table `zipCodesDetails` as `zip_code_details`. Something in laravel is changing the database and table names.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can prevent it? I don't want to just rename the database or table names because while that may get me by in testing it's not a viable solution in practice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the behaviour that uses if no table is being explicitly defined. In your ZipCodeDetails class, you can set the table name that this model will be using.

```
class ZipCodeDetails extends Eloquent 
{
          protected $table = 'zipCodesDetails';
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! That got me past my error. I'll go back and re-read the documentation closer.